# Select text to ellipsise in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Lest simplify my situation to the current:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Red),
) {
    Text(
        text = ELLIPSIZE_THIS_TEXT,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    )
    Text(
        text = LEAVE_THIS_TEXT_NOT_ELLIPSIZED,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Visible,
    )
}
```

[image]

[image]

If I add weight(1f) to the first text modifier, it works as expected, but the Row took all the line. But my goal is to take only required place and if I have not enough place - ellipsize the first text.

[image]

[image]

And I need behavior from images 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fill` property for this . Setting it to false will result in wrapping the text if small and ellipsis text in case its bigger. Try this out .

```
Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .background(Color.Red).padding(10.dp),
) {
    Text(
        text = "Jetpack Compose Ui Tool-kit",
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier=Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))
    Text(
        text = "LEAVE_THIS_TEXT",
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Visible,
    )
}
```